# a family of birds “rule” our skies or “rules” our skies?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I came across this sentence this morning:

> A family of bald eagles **rules** our skies and **patrols** the lake.

I wonder why the author didn't use "rule" and "patrol"? Doesn't "a family of birds" mean more than 2 birds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **family** here is a collective noun describing one group of birds that are all ruling the sky and patrolling the lake as **one single unit**.

The **prepositional phrase** that follows the word family (**of Bald Eagles**) merely functions in the sentence to tell you what type of family is flying. i.e.. Bald eagles **not** crows, penguins or any other type of bird.

The verbs **rules** and **patrols** have to be singular to agree with the singular subject (**family =collective noun =singular**).

**of Bald Eagles** only acts to modify the word family.

Answer (score 3):

The subject of the sentence is "family" rather than "eagles," and "family" is singular.

Indeed if you think about it, "eagles" could imply dozens or hundreds, not at all what is meant. What is meant is a small closely related group conceived as a single collection.